# Disable one of languages for non admin users

Tags: python, django, url, django-admin, multilingual

I am working with django 1.11 and I want to make one of languages, accessible only for logged admins - I mean French version.

**For normal users:**

```
http://www.example.com/en
```

**For admin users:**

```
http://www.example.com/en
http://www.example.com/fr
```

settings.py

```
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French')),
)
```

I had idea with: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` in settings file, for example:

```
if User.is_staff:
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', _('English')),
        ('fr', _('French')),
    )
else:
    LANGUAGES = (
        ('en', _('English')),
    )
```

but I got an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

during import: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Answer (score 0):

This probably means that you cannot call `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` before the settings finished importing/loading.

<strike>You could try to move the `if User.is_staff:` to the end of your settings file, but I'm not sure if that will work either.</strike>

`User.is_staff:` will not work, because `User` is a model (a class), not an user instance. You cannot use that kind of if in the settings, because individual users are only defined inside your request/reponse cycle.

You will have to look for another approach, but I'm not having any ideas right now.

Comment: maybe middleware?

Comment: @user9192656 Hm, yeah, you could try a middleware that raises an error (or redirects to english) if user is not staff but uses french. I never tried conditional availability of languages.

Comment: middleware - that was a solution. Thanks.